# Check or Uncheck Checkbox based on Cell Value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to check or uncheck a checkbox based on a value in a cell.

I have a userform that gets filled out and adds new lines on a worksheet with the relevant information gathered from the userform. I want to be able to search for a particular entry and fill out a neat created form on a excel worksheet (not a userform) using the gathered information. In this form I want to use checkboxes instead of cells to keep it neat and professional.

The reason I am doing this into a worksheet form instead of a userform is to be able to print the form into a PDF document. As far as I am aware it is not possible to print a userform into a PDF document.

If it is working the worksheet form should have checkboxes checked if TRUE is found in the cell from that particular data entry. I can't link a specific cell since it needs to find the correct cell based on the search entry.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do. Consider adding your own attempt here so we can help you. To get you started, check out [`Worksheet_Change()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event handler in VBA to give you context for this operation, as well as [`CheckBox.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.checkbox.value)

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question.

Comment: Can you not just link it to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Following on the comments... @Tom is correct, you can simply link the combobox to the cell in question.

Insert combobox:

[image]

Then simply enter the cell reference in the formula bar you want to link it to. Namely:

[image]